# Can't install Bastion on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: package-management, dependencies

Trying to install Bastion on Ubuntu 19.04 gives me the following errors:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i bastion_1.4-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package bastion.
(Reading database ... 368522 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack bastion_1.4-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bastion (1.4-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bastion:
 bastion depends on libalut0; however:
  Package libalut0 is not installed.
 bastion depends on libsdl-mixer1.2; however:
  Package libsdl-mixer1.2 is not installed.
 bastion depends on libsdl-ttf2.0-0; however:
  Package libsdl-ttf2.0-0 is not installed.
 bastion depends on libsdl-net1.2; however:
  Package libsdl-net1.2 is not installed.
 bastion depends on libsmpeg0; however:
  Package libsmpeg0 is not installed.
 bastion depends on libsdl-gfx1.2-4; however:
  Package libsdl-gfx1.2-4 is not installed.
 bastion depends on libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0; however:
  Package libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package bastion (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bastion
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Not so easy:

1. Install the readily available dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt install libalut0 libsdl-mixer1.2 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libsdl-net1.2 libsmpeg0
   ```
2. Download and install libsdl-gfx1.2-4:

   ```
   wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/132696522/libsdl-gfx1.2-4_2.0.23-3_amd64.deb
   sudo dpkg -i libsdl-gfx1.2-4_2.0.23-3_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Download and install libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:

   ```
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/s2tc/libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0_0~git20131104-1.1_amd64.deb
   sudo dpkg -i libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0_0~git20131104-1.1_amd64.deb
   ```
4. Finally, install Bastion:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i bastion_1.4-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   ```

Comment: If a community volunteer stepped up to check for a compatible license and a correct control file and uploaded Bastion to Debian, then the install would be trivially easy for many users.